# uint32_t has 28 bits instead of 32 bits

Tags: c, gdb, uint

I've encountered a confusing situation. I have this simple addition inside my code:

```
temp = thi + t2lo;
```

I have defined `thi` and `t2lo` as `uint32_t` in my code and `temp` as `uint64_t`:

```
uint32_t thi, tlo, t2hi, t2lo;
uint64_t temp = 0;
```

My code doesn't work properly, so I use gdb to figure out what is going wrong. When I tried to print variables in gdb I've got:

```
(gdb) p/x temp
$1 = 0xfeffff2
(gdb) p/x thi
$2 = 0xff00000
(gdb) p/x t2lo
$3 = 0xfffffff2
```

As you can see here, `thi` has 28 bits instead of 32 bits, and the addition result is completely wrong. Could anyone tell me what is going on here?

**PS:** I have a large code and I cannot put my whole source code here for you guys to reproduce this situation. Also, this situation only occurs for certain inputs and most of the time my code is working correct. I just want to check with you guys if you encountered something like this before.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't put _all_ your code here, just write a small example that shows the problem. If you can't, if the problem disappears when you remove the rest of the code, then it is probably caused by something in that rest of the code, and it will be very hard for us to guess what.

Comment: Having 28bit: The debugger may just omitting leading zeros.

Comment: When I print 10 in decimal it only comes out as `10`. Oh no, that means `int`s can only hold numbers up to 99!

Comment: @immibis: `99!` does not fit in an `int` on most architectures...

Comment: @chqrlie I had assumed most people were smart enough to distinguish between the factorial operator and punctuation. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: @immibis: your comment was sarcastic, so was mine ;-)

Comment: Use `temp = (uint64_t) thi + t2lo;` to get that carry into `temp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `uint32_t` *is* 32 bits, not 28.

What happens here is that the most significant 4 bits are 0, and the leading zeros are not printed by gdb with `p/x`.

`0xff00000` is the same as `0x0ff00000`.

Use `p/z thi` to include the leading zeros when displaying. Have a look here:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html

Answer (score 4):

`temp = (uint64_t)thi + t2lo;`

Without the cast (or something equivalent) the addition will be performed in 32b, then the result extended to 64b. Which is in fact what you are seeing 0xff00000 + 0xfffffff2 = 0x10FEFFFF2 which in 32b arithmetics equals 0xFEFFFF2.

Comment: I used cast but it didn't work. The result is still incorrect

Comment: @Ajeneral: highly unlikely... edit your question and post the actual code as a compilable unit.

Comment: @AJeneral I don't think `p/x` is the right output format for a uint64_t but I don't have gdb handy now to verify.

Comment: You are correct!  comment deleted.  Why would `p/x` not be the right gdb command?  gdb should know `temp` is a 64 bit unsigned int.

Comment: @chqrlie Right, I'll take that back.